# Improving CodeCamper with pagination

Tags: knockout.js, breeze, single-page-application, durandal

I've been watching John Papa's awesome video on Pluralsight for building a SPA.

Now, I'm trying to implement pagination for the Sessions page and I'm not sure if what I've done is the right way to do it. I'd appreciate some feedback if anyone has attempted something similar.

Here's what I've done.

sessions.html

---

```
  <section>
    <footer>
        <ul class="pager">
            <li>
                <button class="btn btn-info btn-small" data-bind="click: previous, enable:canPrev"><i class="icon-angle-left"></i>Previous</button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button class="btn btn-info btn-small" data-bind="click: next, enable: canPrev">Next<i class="icon-angle-right"></i></button>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </footer>
</section>
```

sessions.js

---

```
   var  currentPage = ko.observable(), 

   activate = function () {
        currentPage(0);
        return datacontext.getSessionPartials(sessions);
   },

   previous = function () {
        currentPage(currentPage() - 1);
        return datacontext.getSessionPartials(sessions, true, currentPage());
    },

    canPrev = ko.computed(function () {
        return currentPage() > 0;
    }),

    canNext = ko.computed(function () {
        //return currentPage > 0;
    }),

    next = function () {
        currentPage(currentPage() +1);
        return datacontext.getSessionPartials(sessions, true, currentPage());
    },

   var vm = {
        //existing stuff plus the following:
        previous: previous,
        next: next,
        currentPage: currentPage,
        canPrev: canPrev,
        canNext: canNext,
    };
```

datacontext.js

---

```
 var query = EntityQuery.from('Sessions')
            .select('id, title, code, speakerId, trackId, timeSlotId, roomId, level, tags')
            .skip(currentPage * 5).take(5)                
            .orderBy('timeSlotId, level, speaker.firstName')
            .inlineCount(true);
```

That works, except for the canNext, because I don't know how to add the result of inlineCount to the sessions viewModel. What would be the best way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Breeze you can get as many rows as you want, as Breeze caches them for you in its entity manager. Then show only the ones you want on the page. So for a page size of 20, grab 40 if you like, then show the 20. That way you have the next 20 already and know if there is another page. You can simulate virtual paging this way. Ok, well, its not elegant, but it works :)

Another option is to prime the call with a record count. I recall something vaguely from the Breeze folks saying there might be a way to get the total record count using Breeze. I'll ask them to chime in, as I can't remember concretely.

If you are using the same call to get the data as you are to get the count, then you could set the value to an entity in the datacontext. Or, you could return  from your method a wrapper object that contains your sessions and your count. Something like this...

```
// inside the datacontext method's querySucceeded
// data is your session data you got back
// rowCount is the number of total rows.

return { sessions: data, rowCount: rowCount };
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that you don;t have to worry about getting the same records more than once. Breeze is smart enough to see that you already have some records and merge them.

Comment: Thanks for replying John. Actually your reply surprises me a bit :) Ok, Breeze do caching, but if I have one million records in my database, I certainly don't want to get them all at once, that would take forever. Hence the need for 'real' paging. You can get the total record count with the inlineCount() function, as shown in my code above. However my question to you was more related to how I should pass that information to the Sessions ViewModel when the query is executed in the datacontext service. Hope that makes sense.... ?

Comment: If you have 1 million records, yeah, dont go get them all. Use paging. You asked how to know if you have more pages. That's the second part of the answer: make a call for the record count so you know what's coming. The datacontext or some dataservice module should handle this, and the viewmodel just asks for it.

Comment: I see, so the datacontext would keep track of how many records there is, and the viewmodel does not hold this data, right ? At first, I thought it'd be best to store this information in the Sessions viewmodel itself. On the other hand, the datacontext service could be used for many more types of viewmodels, in which case, would it not seem a bit strange to keep viewmodel-related data into the datacontext ? Thanks for helping me !

Comment: The session data would certainly be cached in the datacontext. The session count could go there too, as a separate entity. If you really want to go all out you can create a client side entity that stores the counts of entities ... might be overkill tho. If you stored the record count in the viewmodel, thats fine too. The key is making the datacontext go and get it.

Comment: Actually my personal preference would be to store the count in the viewmodel, but like I said in my original post, I don't know how to assign it to the viewmodel. In the querySucceeded(data) method, I can get the count by doing data.inlineCount, but then I have no idea how to pass that to the viewmodel from there.

Comment: Thanks John. Actually I just figured out that I could simply pass an extra parameter to getSessionsPartials such as countObservable. Then I can set the value to data.inlineCount. That seems neat enough, what do you think ?

Comment: I'm cautious of output parameters as its not as intuitive when reading the code that its intended to return 1 thing from the function and another from the parameter. Just my personal preference :)

Comment: Very true. Since you were already passing the sessionsObservable as parameter, I thought I'd do the same for the count. However, the code you provided above does not fit in the querySucceeded() method as it's not supposed to return anything, unless I've missed something here ?

Comment: yes, sorry. i was thinking of other code :) ... you can pass 2 parms in. I try to limit it, and might be tempted to pas in a wrapper object. but i think 2 arms is fine in this case.

Answer (score 4):

to get inlineCount add this line in datacontext.js

```
   var getSessionPartials = function (sessionsObservable, totalpages,totalrecords, currentPage) {

        var query = EnityQuery.from('Sessions')
               .select('id, title, code, speakerId, trackId, timeSlotId, roomId, level, tags')
               .skip(currentPage * 5).take(5)
               .where("title","startsWith","A")
               .orderBy('timeSlotId, level, speaker.firstName')
               .inlineCount(true);


        return manager.executeQuery(query)
                .then(querySucceeded)
                .fail(queryFailed);

        function querySucceeded(data) {
            var list = partialMapper.mapDtosToEntities(
               manager, data.results, entityNames.session, 'id'
               );

            if (sessionsObservable) {
                sessionsObservable(list);
                totalpages(Math.ceil(data.inlineCount / 10));
                totalrecords(data.inlineCount);
            }

            log('Retireved Sessions from remote datasource', data, true);
        }
    };
```

in session.js add

```
var currentPage = ko.observable();
var totalPages = ko.observable();
var totalrecords = ko.observable();


canNext = ko.computed(function () {
    return currentPage() < totalPages();
    //return true;
});
```

Comment: that's what I ended up doing, thanks for your feedback. I can't mark it as answer as I've already done it for John's. Thanks !